# More GNU make: What could cause the shell (default = /bin/sh) to start saying "@mkdir: not found"?

Tags: gnu-make

I'm starting to think I have broken GNU make. Its behavior seems to have become unpredictable. Do I get a prize for that?
In my commands section, I have been using the '@' character to suppress unwanted output. In one makefile, I removed the '@'s for one run, to verify it was doing what I wanted. Since I put the '@'s back in, I'm getting shell errors:
@mkdir: not found
What in the world is ***that*** about? What could make the '@' stop being recognized as a standard command modifier?
Grrrr! I hates that potto! (from the cover of Managing projects with GNU make)

Comment: Could you post the relevant snippet of your `Makefile`?

Comment: Did you happen to insert a backslash at the end of the line before the line with `@mkdir`? FYI: an alternative way to verify what make is doing is to use `make "SHELL=sh -x" target`. The shell will then print every command executed, even if it starts with `@`.

Comment: Reinier has the most likely answer.  Also note a simpler way to do this is to set a variable like `V := @` then use `$V` in your rules instead of `@`; now when you want to see the rules you just run `make V=` to remove the `@`.  In the next release of GNU make there will be a trace flag that lets you turn off `@`.

Comment: Yes, Reinier was correct. Those were continued lines in the command section, so the previous line did end with a backslash. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The `@` character is only valid at the beginning of a line executed by make. If you have continuation characters such as `\`  ending the previous line, this won't be executed by make, it will be executed by the shell. The shell won't know what to do with the `@` sign, hence your error.

Additionally if you use `.ONESHELL` you should note that command prefix will only be valid on the very  first line of the recipe, after that it will throw an error since all the lines are passed to one shell for execution.

The same rules apply to the other prefix operator (`-`) as well.